# Why can't I login to the GUI via lxdm after upgrading to lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: boot, login, lubuntu, 13.04

When I boot to the login screen, I can put in my credentials but nothing happens after that. I left my laptop over night and it still didn't log in. The only thing I can do is hit ctrl, alt f2 to get a terminal and run startx which required me to install gnome shell (ugh). If I run startlxde, I get an error saying that it can't connect to the display.

Edited: It seems the issue is with lxdm. LightDM allows me to login just fine.

Comment: Are you able to log in with command line.

Comment: It happens to me too. When I enter my credentials the system does nothing, no disk/process activity. `startx` works though.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `lightdm` instead of `lxdm` as display manager. That worked for me.

Although I can't explain why it fails with `lxdm`, only found some "cannot connect to X" messages at `.cache/lxsession/LXDE/run.log`.

Comment: Hey cool switching to lightdm worked well. Now to figure out what the hell is wrong with lxdm.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.

```
sudo mv -v .Xauthority .Xauthoritybak
sudo shutdown now -r
```

It should now work.